# WCF Invoking Exception

Tags: wcf

The caller was not authenticated by the service.The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.

Iam getting this Exception when i tried to invoke WCF service.
Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy answer. Here are questions for troubleshooting:

What type of client? Does the client support the same security mode as the server? Do you have Service Tracing on and have you examined the trace with the Service Trace Viewer Tool (http://goo.gl/6GXvf)?

Looking at the trace, it appears a problem authenticating the client, but it could be an underlying issue.